# How to post to the endpoint: /myproject/notification/{nId}

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, urllib

I need to send the notification to the endpoint (websockets configured). This notification should be sent from Python 3:

```
POST  /myproject/notification/{nId}
```

I found some examples how to send Json data, but I only need to send the notification id `nId`

```
import urllib.request
import json      

data = {'ids': [1, 2, 3]}  

myurl = "localhost"
req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(data)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

How can I do the same for `POST  /myproject/notification/{nId}`?

I tried this code, but it failed.

```
data = 1

myurl = "localhost/myproject/notification/"
req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(data)
```

**I would prefer to use `requests` library instead of `urllib`.**

```
r = requests.post("localhost/myproject/notification/", data=1)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send an empty POST to that URL, then just do so. There's no need to supply a data parameter if you don't have any to send.

```
requests.post('http://localhost/myproject/notification/{}'.format(nId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It simply calls simply url endpoint with pseudo-data.

```
requests.post("localhost/myproject/notification/"+str(nId), data=dummydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.6, you can use f-strings to format your strings.

```
 requests.post(f'http://localhost/myproject/notification/{nId}')
```